Filter console exceptions in Log4j from executed jar
I am running a minecraft server and some addons keep spamming the console (and hence making it useless) with the following:
com.mojang.brigadier.exceptions.CommandSyntaxException
I want to get rid of this!
I need the correct log4j tag when running the jar and also the correct external log4j configuration file (xml only).
What I have tried:
I add the following parameters into executing the jar so it reads:
java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/container/console.xml -Xms128M -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=95.0 -jar server.jar
Key here is:
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/container/console.xml
I then put the following console.xml file into /home/container/ where it sits next to the server.jar file.
In the console.xml file, I made from: How to filter a specific exception from Log4j? the following configuration:
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="System.out">
        <RegexFilter regex=".*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-2p %c{1.} %x - %m%n"/> 
    </Console>
    <File name="logfile" filename="./app.log" append="true">
        <RegexFilter regex=".*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{-1} %X{userName} - %m%n"/> 
    </File>
</Appenders>

This however did nothing! And the Log4j debug did not help.

You have typos in your system properties: the officially supported names are log4j2.debug and log4j2.configurationFile. Small variation might also work, but log4j.configuration certainly won't (it is the Log4j 1 name of the property).

Please add concrete examples of log messages you want to filter out. Edit your question, don't post them as comments.

Lets try to explicitly filter out the CommandSyntaxException messages.
Also lets change onMismatch="NEUTRAL" to onMismatch="ACCEPT"
e.g. below
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="System.out">
        <RegexFilter regex=".*com\.mojang\.brigadier\.exceptions\.CommandSyntaxException.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-2p %c{1.} %x - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="logfile" filename="./app.log" append="true">
        <RegexFilter regex=".*com\.mojang\.brigadier\.exceptions\.CommandSyntaxException.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{-1} %X{userName} - %m%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>

And then execute
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/container/console.xml -Xms128M -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=95.0 -jar server.jar


This will probably not work, since the RegexFilter matches the regular exception against the log message and exceptions are not part of the log message (they are part of the log event). See messages for a short introduction to all the components of a log event.
